# Library not found for -lSDL

Tags: c++, g++, sdl

I am trying to compile a C++ program that uses SDL using the g++ compiler.  I just downloaded SDL and put the SDL.framework into the /Library/Frameworks directory on my computer.  My compile line includes

```
-L/Library/Frameworks -lSDL
```

This causes the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lSDL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

How can I get this to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `-framework SDL` on OS X, not `-lSDL` (unless you install SDL as a library, which is also possible).  You will also want `-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers`, I think.